# How to access component's properties without knowing its name?

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to use the properties of a component created in run-time without knowing its name? And by this I mean after you already done this.

```
with TPanel.Create(self) do
  begin
  Name := 'Panel' + IntToStr(ComponentCount + 1);
  Height := 50;
  Width := 100;
  Top := 30;
  Left := 30;
  Parent := self;
  end;
```

Comment: Store the objects in a container, like  `TList<TPanel>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare a variable of type `TPanel` and store a reference to your component in that variable.

```
var
  Panel: TPanel;
.... 
Panel := TPanel.Create(Self);
```

You can then refer to the control using this variable.

You will likely need to hold the variable as a member field of the form, or in an array, or indeed some other container.

Comment: i'm dealing with unlimited number of components .

Comment: They can't all be called panel1 then. Store them in an array or another container, as it says in the answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The answer is the same.

Comment: You know, after 8 months, I think I would like to say I'm sorry I accepted the other answer instead of yours. I should've known better (well I did not have the same knowledge as I do now). thank you for your help.

Comment: And by the way, The container I'm using to store the panels is `TList` (the generics version).