# Ownership principles when using tpagecontrol

Tags: delphi, generics

Two days ago I gave an accepted answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760663/delphi-already-opened-tab-in-pagecontrol/43762705#43762705) (that is what bothering me the most):

```
  newtabsheet:=ttabsheet.Create(PageControl1);
  NewTabSheet.PageControl := PageControl1;
  newtabsheet.Caption:='tab1';
  i1:=tabs.Count;
  tabs.Add(newtabsheet);
```

I have analysed this code the best I can, and these are my results.

**Line 1:** I create a `ttabsheet` with `pagecontrol1` as the parent/owner (based on the constructor below).

```
constructor TTabSheet.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  Align := alClient;
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls, csNoDesignVisible,
    csParentBackground, csPannable];
  Visible := False;
  FTabVisible := True;
  FHighlighted := False;
end;
```

Then I stored a reference to it in the variable `Newtabsheet` (this remarque is based on an answer @David Heffernan gave to [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312513/how-to-access-components-properties-without-knowing-its-name) of my questions).

**Line 2:** I used the reference to assign `pagecontrol1` to the property `.pagecontrol`.

And this is the code of the setting method:

```
procedure TTabSheet.SetPageControl(APageControl: TPageControl);
begin
  if FPageControl <> APageControl then
  begin
    if FPageControl <> nil then
      FPageControl.RemovePage(Self);
    Parent := APageControl;
    if APageControl <> nil then
      APageControl.InsertPage(Self);
  end;
end;
```

Based on this I think (maybe wrong) it is comparing the existing parent to the new passed parameter, if there is a different then if the `parent<>nil` removes this `newtabsheet` from the previous `pagecontrol` (visual affects) and assign it to the new parent/owner, then if the new `parent<>nil` insert it in the new `pagecontrol`(visual affects).

So this line is unnecessary (maybe wrong), because I already did that in the first line.

**Line 3:** I use the reference to assign the caption of the `tabsheet` with 'tab1'.

**Line 5:** I use the add method to store a reference to the `tabsheet` in the tabs list `tabs:TList<ttabsheet>;` a generic.

Here is where things start to fly over my head.

I think that the parent/owner is `tabs`, but the `pagecontrol1` is still showing the tab (based on the accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635461/drag-drop-listboxitems-from-listbox1-to-listbox2-with-their-images-and-avoiding) changing the parent visually removes the `tabsheet` from `pagecontrol1`), but it does not.

Now this could be wrong, but again if it is just a reference then why when I delete the `tabsheet` from `pagecontrol1` by doing  `PageControl1.ActivePage.free` the `tabs.count` remains constant.

And if I delete the `tabsheet` from tabs then the `tabsheet` on the `pagecontrol1` is not deleted (removed visually).

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463968/example-for-using-generics-collections-tobjectdictionary/8466317#8466317) I understood that generics becomes the parent/owner and that you do not need to worry about freeing `tabsheet` from `pagecontrol1`, because tabs is the parent and you only need to free it from `tabs`.

**My question:** What is happening in this code and why I'm facing this behavior?

#### Clarification

What is driving the question is when I delete the ttabsheet in the pagecontrol why it is not raising an error when I try to use the reference to it in the list are they two different objects.

Comment: The generic list knows nothing about page controls. It doesn't interfere with parent or owner relationships. Not sure what the question really is. So many excerpts of code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my question is why when I delete the tabsheet from the list it is not deleted from the pagecontrol1 and vice versa?.

Comment: Why should it? The `tabs` list is just a parallel reference to the tabsheet. The owner (= responsible for lifetime management) is the `PageControl`.

Comment: `Owner`is reponsible of freeing an object when not needed anymore. `Parent` provides a surface for visual controls to render themselves. `Owner` and `Parent` can be the same but doesn't have to be. In case of the `PageControl` (which is a Windows control) the `PageControl` property is overruling the `Parent`property, therefore changing the `Parent` of a `TTabSheet` doesn't affect its visibility. You refer to another question (moving listitems between LB1 and LB2). That is a completely different issue. The question is about Firemonkey and about listboxes, not Microsoft PageControls.

Comment: @TomBrunberg could you explain the other way around, I mean when I delete  the tab from the pagecontrol why it is not deleted from the list. or at least gives some error when using the reference.

Comment: @TomBrunberg the other question is about firmonkey but still the idea about parent relationships is the same.

Comment: As David already said, the list knows nothing about the page control and vv. If you have to variables, A and B holding references to one and same object, and you remove the reference from A, you can still use B to access the object.

Comment: But, if you **destroy** the one and only object using reference A (or B), it is unusable from both A and B.

Comment: @tom If I use free isn't that destroying the ttabsheet.

Comment: Yes, that is covered by the "destroying". But I don't see any calls to Free in the codes above?

Comment: @tom `PageControl1.ActivePage.free`  read carefully it is written above, after the line 5 paragraph.

Comment: Found it in the text. Well I said "it is unusable". Once you have destroyed an object nothing guarantees that you can use it further. In most cases you will get an error if you try, but under some circumstances you may be able to e.g. read some properties, because the objects data structure is still residing in memory. You need to read up on memory management, objects memory model and remember that there are differencies between Vcl and Fmx and the various platforms.

Comment: @tom will do. Is just I thought that if I use it again I will get an error but that is not the case here.

Comment: *...by doing PageControl1.ActivePage.free the tabs.count remains constant.* I once more want to emphasize, the list and the pagecontrol have **no knowledge** of each other, IOW freeing a tabsheet has no effect on the list, and especially not on the lists count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Owner` is responsible for **memory management**.  Assigning the `TPageControl` as the `Owner` of the `TTabSheet` means the `TPageControl` will destroy the `TTabSheet` when the `TPageControl` is destroyed.  The `Owner` and ownee contain pointers to each other so they can notify each other of important events related to memory management.

The `Parent` is responsible for **window management** and visual presentation. Assigning the `TPageControl` as the `Parent` of the `TTabSheet` means the `TTabSheet`'s window is a child of the `TPageControl`'s window, and will be displayed inside the client area of the `TPageControl`'s window. The `Parent` and child contain pointers to each other so they can notify each other of important events related to window management.

The `Owner` and `Parent` are **two different things**. They *can* be the same object, but they don't have to be  (case in point - components created at design-time are always owned by the `TForm`, `TFrame`, or `TDataModule` that is being designed, but can be children of container components, like `TPanel`, etc).

The `TList` is responsible for **nothing**.  It is just a dynamic array of arbitrary values, which in this case happen to be `TTabSheet` pointers. Nothing more.  There is no Owner/Parent relationship between the `TList` and `TTabSheet` at all.

When the `TTabSheet` is destroyed, there are relational links between itself and its `TPageControl`. The `TTabSheet` removes itself from its `TPageControl`'s management. It is no longer owned by the `TPageControl`, and is no longer a child of the `TPageControl`. The two objects clear their pointers to each other.

There is no relational link between the `TTabSheet` and the `TList` at all.  The `TTabSheet` has no concept that the `TList` even exists.  When the `TTabSheet` is added to and removed from the `TList`, the `TList` is simply adding/removing *a pointer to* the `TTabSheet` object. The `TList` does not notify the `TTabSheet` about the insertion/removal. And there is no pointer from the `TTabSheet` to the `TList`, so when the `TTabSheet` is destroyed, there is no mechanism in place that allows the pointer to that `TTabSheet` to be removed from the `TList`.  The pointer remains in the list, and you can continue using the pointer (for comparisons, etc) as long as you do not dereference it to access the destroyed `TTabSheet`.

If you want to remove the `TTabSheet` pointer from the `TList` automatically when the `TTabSheet` is destroyed, you need to call the `TTabSheet`'s `FreeNotification()` method. Your `Notification()` callback can then remove the `TTabSheet` pointer from the `TList` in response to `opRemove` notifications, eg:

```
TMyForm = class(TForm)
  ...
private
  tabs: TList<TTabSheet>;
  ...
protected
  procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override; // <-- ADD THIS
  ...
end;

...  

procedure TMyForm.DoSomething;
var
  NewTabSheet: TTabSheet;
  ...
begin
  ...
  NewTabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1);
  NewTabSheet.PageControl := PageControl1;
  NewTabSheet.Caption := 'tab1';
  tabs.Add(NewTabSheet);
  NewTabSheet.FreeNotification(Self); // <-- ADD THIS
  ...
end;

procedure TMyForm.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent is TTabSheet) then
    tabs.Remove(TTabSheet(AComponent)); // <-- HERE
end;
```

If you want the `TTabSheet` to be removed from its `TPageControl` automatically when its pointer is removed from the `TList`, switch to `TObjectList` instead.  Its `OwnsObjects` property is true by default, so it will destroy the `TTabSheet` when the pointer is removed from the list using the `Remove()` or `Delete()` method.  The `Extract()` method will not destroy the `TTabSheet`, so use that instead of `Remove()` in your `Notification()` callback, eg:

```
TMyForm = class(TForm)
  ...
private
  tabs: TObjectList<TTabSheet>;
  ...
end;

...  

procedure TMyForm.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent is TTabSheet) then
    tabs.Extract(TTabSheet(AComponent)); // <-- HERE
end;
```

Comment: I have tried this solution, in this question and it gave me an error. can you tell me more about freenotification method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487294/deleting-an-fmxobject-inside-its-event-handler.

Comment: That is way too much code to look through, and too little description.  I'm not going to spend my time trying to figure it out. You need to debug it for yourself.

Comment: I later found the problem about the use of the `FreeNotification` method. In the question I linked above. thank you