# Delphi - Destroy Parent Component

Tags: delphi, free, destroy

Inside a ScrollBox I create in runtime some panels and inside each panel I create a frame with the panel as Parent.

Inside the frame I have a button that should Destroy the frame and the Panel.

How can I destroy the panel and the frame from that button?

Comment: Post a message to allocated invisible window and when that window receives it, remove that panel from the scroll box.

Comment: Isn't the Release method designed for this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Release is for forms, specifically TCustomFrom descendants. But the similar principle can be implemented for any control.

Comment: Sorry, I thought Release was available for a win control.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Unfortunately, it is not. But it would make every sense to be there, too.

Comment: Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487294/deleting-an-fmxobject-inside-its-event-handler) it has what you want. You need to create a new component though.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan in the link above I used release to free the component (`TGroupBox`). second code the last 3 lines

Comment: Only FMX objects  has `Release` method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31785692/how-to-free-a-control-in-a-own-event